# Is it possible to encrypt 2 SSD disks in software RAID 1 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, raid-1, password-protection

How can I best protect / encrypt two SSD disks in software RAID 1? Windows 10 doesn't offer the BitLocker option on RAID 1 disks, but still I would like to encrypt them somehow. Especially for the situation when the whole server gets stolen.

Comment: Maybe you can use SED somehow. The whole thing sounds far fetched and ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0):

Store critical files/softwares in encrypted VHD (Virtual Hard Disk).

You need to unlock volumes manually (automatic with local stored key unsafe) on every restart (but normally it not happens often).

1. Create VHD on the software RAID volume, encrypt it with ex. BitLocker.
2. Install critical data/softwares to the VHD disk (you can use separate drive letter or attach it to an empty folder).
3. Each time you restart system, you need to unlock the VHD manually (you
   can do it via Remote Desktop or BitLocker Network Unlock feature)

One of my server storage is 8x8TB hard disk drives, all in one spanned volume. I created a 64TB VHDX, encrypted with BitLocker. If server was stolen, I don't worry about the data, because unlock key not stored on the server.

Comment: "all in one spanned volume" >> So if one of your hard disks fails, all is lost?

Answer (score -1):

Bitlocker dosen't support encryption of SOFTWARE RAID, only hardware RAID.

Comment: I think question already states similar.